# How to overwrite ember-data reader method? or convert DS.attr to computed property? similar to backbone parse

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an endpoint that returns `id, name, properties`, and properties is a damn string, with comma separated attribute key/value pairs. Yes you read that correctly.

properties = `"id:1,name:foobar,phone:123456789,taco:true"`

Current Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  contact: DS.belongsTo("contact"),

  name: DS.attr(),
  phone: DS.attr(),
  properties: DS.attr(),
  eachProperties: function () {
    return this.get('properties').split(",").map(function(propertyKeyValuePair) {
      return propertyKeyValuePair.split(":");
    });
  }.property('properties')
});
```

`properties` requires some computation to be helpful on the front-end.

Can you re-use the property named `properties` instead of creating a new one called `eachProperties`?

Something like:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // ... other stuff

  properties: DS.attr(function(model, obj){
    return obj.split(",").map(function(propertyKeyValuePair) {
      return propertyKeyValuePair.split(":");
    });
  });
});
```

OR how does one change the name of an api property name to something else like `rawProperties` and then have the computed property called `properties`?

I know you're thinking **"Just fix your damn API"** but you know that isn't always possible :)

Comment: Don't "fix your damn API", read about serializers and get rid of `properties, eachProperties` which don't represent model data.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you! Are serializers used WITH models??

Comment: looks like i need to create a transform for this property?http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html

Comment: I can only tell that you need to work with `Adapters` and/or `Serializers`. I don't have enough knowledge to answer your specific questions. : /

Comment: Ultimately, what form do you want to transform the data inside of `properties` into?  Separate properties on your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that i basically wanted to utilize [Transforms (docs)](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html) to handle the deserializing. Its super easy and rad.

As per [Ember-CLI module-directory-naming-structure](http://www.ember-cli.com/#module-directory-naming-structure), you add transforms inside the `app/transforms/` folder.
I created a file called `properties.js`. *(Whatever you name the file will be the name of attribute/transform.)*

```
//*inside app/transforms/properties.js*


import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function (serialized) {
    return serialized.split(",").map(function (keyValuePair) {
      return keyValuePair.split(":");
    });
  },
  serialize: function (deserialized) {
    return deserialized.map(function (keyValuePair) {
      return keyValuePair.join(":");
    }).join(",");
  }
});
```

This transform will be used when you receive json, and also when you send the JSON back out! super cool.

Updated Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  contact: DS.belongsTo("contact"),

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr(),
  properties: DS.attr('properties')
});
```

the `DS.attr('properties')` is where the magic happens!